# Python Logging across multiple classes and files; how to configure so as to be easily disabled?

Tags: python, logging

Currently, I have osmething like this in all of my classes:

```
# Import logging to log information
import logging

# Set up the logger
LOG_FILENAME = 'log.txt'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)
```

This works well, and I get the output I want, but I would really like to have all this sort of information in one place, and be able to just do something like `import myLogger` and then start logging, and then hopefully be able to just go into that file and turn off logging when I need an extra performance boost.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simply the setting up of logging, check out [logging.config](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#configuring-logging).

To disable logging, you could use the command

```
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Answer (score 3):

To disable all logging from the root logger (which is all you're setting up with `basicConfig`),

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

If you want, you can encapsulate that into a function of your `myLogger` module, but that hardly seems worth it.

Comment: Python gave me an error with the `getHandler()` call: module object has no attribute gethandler.

Comment: Oops, typo/thinko -- I meant `getLogger` of course, let me edit to fix (sorry!).